# Password Hashing and Verify in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter-3, password-protection, password-encryption, password-hash

So I'm having a trouble in which I try to log in a user with a password store in the database:

I currently have this for my login function and model:

Controller:

```
$username = $this->input->post('username');    
$password = $this->input->post('password');
$enc_password = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
$data_user = $this->User_model->login($username, $enc_password);
```

Model:

```
public function login($username, $enc_password)
{
    $this->db->where('username', $username);
    $this->db->where("password", $enc_password);
    $this->db->where("password2", $enc_password);

    $query = $this->db->get($this->table);

    $hashed_password = $enc_password;

    if (password_verify($hashed_password, $hashed_password)) {
        return $query->row();
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Can somebody tell me where is my error? I'm trying to log in the user after the typed password matches with both the "password" and "password2" which are created the same(in register function; same password hash) but for some reason it does not let me it even when I type the correct password. :/

Thanks in advance.

Comment: fetch the row first according to username, then make the verify comparison using the fetched password row to the submitted input password

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just like what I mentioned in the comments, don't touch (apply) anything on the input password.
Fetch the row according to username first. Get the hashed password and compare it in the inputted password.

Here's the idea:

```
public function login($username, $password)
{
    // fetch by username first
    $this->db->where('username', $username);
    $query = $this->db->get($this->table);
    $result = $query->row_array(); // get the row first

    if (!empty($result) && password_verify($password, $result['password'])) {
        // if this username exists, and the input password is verified using password_verify
        return $result;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Just make sure you have `password_hash`ed password in your user table (I'm assuming you already handled this part).

So the usage would be like so:

```
$username = $this->input->post('username');    
$password = $this->input->post('password');
$data_user = $this->User_model->login($username, $password);
```

Just feed in the password, no need to hash it when logging in. You use `password_hash` on registration.

Comment: @Kevin sure glad this helped

Answer (score 0):

be sure, you have just stored hashed password in database

In your controller

```
$username = $this->input->post('username');    
$password = $this->input->post('password');
$data_user = $this->User_model->login($username, $password);
```

In Your Model

```
public function login($username, $password)
{
   $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * from table where username = $username");

    $row = $query->row();


    if (password_verify($password,$row->password)) {
        return $query->row();
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```